# How to convert promise<any[]> to any[] : problem with async, await, promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a problem with async, await and promise.
Here is my code block, but I've faced following error.

> Type 'Promise<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

in

> objectList = this.markRequired(objectList, requiredList, typeCodeName);

what is the matter?

```js
async applyRequiredTypes(objectList: any[], typeCodeName: any, requiredList: any[]) {
  objectList = objectList || [];
  requiredList = requiredList || [];
  objectList = this.markRequired(objectList, requiredList, typeCodeName);
  ...
}

async markRequired(itemList: any[], requiredList: any[], typeCodeName: any) {
  return itemList.map((item: any) => {
    item.required = requiredList.some((requiredTypeCode) => {
      return requiredTypeCode === item[typeCodeName];
    });
    return item;
  });
}
```

Comment: Wait for the promise to resolve before using it: `objectList = await this.markRequired(...)`.

Comment: Why is `markRequired` an `async` function? There's nothing asynchronous in it.

Comment: That `return itemList.map(...)` could be a simple `.forEach()` because you're not returning a clone of `item` but instead modify the elements in `itemList` directly.

Comment: @caTS
Thank you, But I can't fix it

`objectList = await this.markRequired(objectList, requiredList, typeCodeName);`  
**'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308)**

Comment: Nothing in your example does something asynchronous, so once again... Why are those functions marked as `async`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to await `markRequired()`.

```
objectList = await this.markRequired(objectList, requiredList, typeCodeName);
```

To answer your last comment, you can only use await inside of an async function, or at the top level (not inside a class or function) with new versions of Node.

`markRequired()` is not doing anything async, you don't need to make it an async function.